# Ruby on Rails - ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

Am working on some guest account feature in my game application.If u register as a game user then devise gem loads the current account id to the session automatically. But when a user is a guest, am creating a account and a user type object with hard coded values and saving that to the database successfully. But when I try to store the object into the session its not working properly.

My code is like this,

```
def play_as_guest
   account = Account.new(email: "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@eossys.com", password: "password", is_guest: true)
   account.save
   game_user = GameUser.new(account: account, game_profile_attributes: {first_name: "Guest", last_name: "guest", nick_name: "guest"})
   game_user.save
   session[:current_account] = game_user
   redirect_to "/game_profiles/#{account.id}/summary"
end
```

If i store the account obj
session[:current_account] = game_user

this is throwing an error of "ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in HomeController#play_as_guest"

if I try
session[:current_account_account] = account

its not working, because after redirecting its again asking for the login. since I am using the 'authenticate_account!' filter in every class.

What I want basically is to load the account object I have created into the session, like as if its a registered user.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: sign_in account - this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need the code of your `authenticate_account!` filter to answer it properly but for your error, this is because you try to put an entire object in your session, it is better to only put the `id` of the object in it :

```
session[:current_account] = game_user.id
```

UPDATE

With devise you should use the `sign_in` method to set the session for this user instead of manually setting the session variable, depending of how your are using devise it could be:

`sign_in account` or `sign_in game_user`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both session[:current_account] = game_user.id

Comment: At least my solution should prevent the `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` to answer for your authentication problem please give us the code of `authenticate_account!` filter.

Comment: that problem occurs only when I try to  store the game_user. and We are just using the Devise gem and there is code for authenticate! filter. If I am storing the account object into session its executing without errors but again its asking for a login.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please let me know if it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Rails cookies have a maximum limit of 4k ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage ). When you do something like `obj session[:current_account] = game_user`, you are attempting to stuff the whole game_user object in there, which causes you to run out of room with the `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error you mentioned. The preferred way to do this is to save only the id, like this `obj session[:current_account_id] = game_user.id`,and look it up when you need it. This is much more efficient, even if your whole object did fit into memory somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its working fine with session[:current_account] = account .

Comment: is this code is correct session[:current_account] = account.id.